# How to define an immediate resource based on an application resource in SL4?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I would like to know if there is a way to define an immediate resource (defined in a user control or page) based on an application resource (defined in App.xaml)?

So, if I had a resource in my App.xaml like:

```
<my:ParentResource x:Key="AppResource" />
```

I could create an immediate resource based on a property of the application resource.  Something like:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:ChildResource x:Key="LocalResource" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Where ChildResource is actually created/instantiated/found as a property on the ParentResource class, such as ParentResource.Child.

Is this possible in Silverlight 4?